# URL in Joomla does not work

Tags: joomla

I have a live joomla website which i copied on my development server which has the URL "dev.xxx.ch". The base site works but when i click on a link it fails. The link is generated right: dev.xxx.ch/gyger/ but then the sites goes to xxx.ch

Can anybody fix me?

Comment: In the config file gives proper url for site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `configuration.php` file in your root directory. This line should say:

```
public $live_site = 'http://dev.pingag.ch';
```

If it doesn't change it. With that said, that's not the only thing you need to worry about. Make sure you have followed the proper directions on [copying over a site](http://docs.joomla.org/Copying_a_Joomla_website).

I also highly recommend using [Akeeba backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/). It is free and takes care of everything for you. Really the only way to go. Although a word of warning with Akeeba backup, make sure to follow the documentation carefully, it will save you tons of time.